# Log4perl configuration is not working

Tags: linux, perl, logging, log4perl

I have Log4perl installed on my Linux machine and have the following `/path/to/log4perl.conf`:

```
log4perl.logger.Fizz = INFO, FizzAppender
log4perl.logger.Buzz = INFO, BuzzAppender

log4perl.appender.FizzAppender = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.filename = /my/logs/fizz-log.txt
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.max = 1
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.TZ = EST
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %m %n

log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.filename = /my/logs/buzz-log.txt
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.max = 1
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.TZ = EST
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %m %n
```

Inside each of my perl scripts (each script uses a different appender and a logs to a different log file):

```
use Log::Log4perl;

my $log_conf = "/path/to/log4perl.conf";
Log::Log4perl::init($log_conf);

# In one script the logger is a "Fizz" logger (like below), and in the other
# script the logger is a "Buzz" logger.
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("Fizz");

$logger->info("This should work.");
```

Even though each script uses a different appender and logs to a different file, they should all have the same behavior:

- Each log gets rotated once a day, and old (rotated) logs gets deleted

I've had this script running for more than 24 hours now, and I don't see *any* logs being generated under `/my/logs/`.

So I ask: **is my `log4perl.conf` incorrect? If not, what can I do to diagnose the issue?** Am I initializing the library incorrectly in the perl scripts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should also note that I *only* installed the main Log4perl module, so if `Log::Dispatch::FileRotate` is not apart of `Log4perl`, then I would say that's obviously it.  However I've read documentation online that suggests both ways, so I'm confused as to whether or not I need to install anything else...

Comment: If you add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your sample code and then run only that, what errors do you get on screen?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the parameter `mode` to your `log4perl.conf` file:

```
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.mode = truncate
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.mode = truncate
```

To speed things along I've changed your DatePattern to the following:

```
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd-HH-MM
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd-HH-MM
```

Here's a test using your `log4perl.conf` file. I've created 2 copies of your `Perl` script:

- log4perl_Buzz.pl
- log4perl_Fizz.pl

I've added a loop within the scripts so that every second they log a message to their respective log files:

```
while (1) {
  $logger->info("This should work.");
  sleep 1;
}
```

I run them both at the same time and see the following results using a `watch ls -l`:

```
Every 2.0s: ls -l                    Thu Dec 20 21:16:51 2012

total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 358 Dec 20 20:15 log4perl_Buzz.pl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 978 Dec 20 21:07 log4perl.conf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 358 Dec 20 20:15 log4perl_Fizz.pl
```

After I run the 2 scripts:

```
Every 2.0s: ls -l                    Thu Dec 20 21:17:56 2012

total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  39 Dec 20 21:17 buzz-log.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  39 Dec 20 21:17 fizz-log.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 358 Dec 20 20:15 log4perl_Buzz.pl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 978 Dec 20 21:07 log4perl.conf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 358 Dec 20 20:15 log4perl_Fizz.pl
```

After ~2 minutes pass:

```
Every 2.0s: ls -l                    Thu Dec 20 21:19:05 2012

total 28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  195 Dec 20 21:19 buzz-log.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 2340 Dec 20 21:18 buzz-log.txt.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  234 Dec 20 21:19 fizz-log.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 2301 Dec 20 21:18 fizz-log.txt.1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml  358 Dec 20 20:15 log4perl_Buzz.pl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  978 Dec 20 21:07 log4perl.conf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml  358 Dec 20 20:15 log4perl_Fizz.pl
```

Here's my version of `log4perl.conf` for those that are playing at home 8-).

```
log4perl.logger.Fizz = INFO, FizzAppender
log4perl.logger.Buzz = INFO, BuzzAppender

log4perl.appender.FizzAppender = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.filename = fizz-log.txt
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.max = 1
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd-HH-MM
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.TZ = EST
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %m %n
log4perl.appender.FizzAppender.mode = truncate

log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.filename = buzz-log.txt
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.max = 1
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd-HH-MM
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.TZ = EST
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %m %n
log4perl.appender.BuzzAppender.mode = truncate
```

These were useful resources in figuring this out:

- [Log::Dispatch::FileRotate on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Dispatch-FileRotate/FileRotate.pm)
- [log4perl FAQ](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html)
- [Limiting log size with log4perl - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648566/limiting-log-size-with-log4perl)